# Product of integers in list without libraries

Tags: python, numpy, zip, list-comprehension

Let's say I'm not allowed to use libraries.
How do I go about calculating the product of indexes in a list.
Let's assume none of the integers are 0 or less.
The problem gets harder as I'm trying to calculate the indexes vertically.

```
bigList = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
           [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
           [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
           [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
           [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

With numpy the solution for my problem would be:

```
import numpy as np   
print([np.prod(l) for l in zip(*bigList)])

[1, 32, 243, 1024, 3125]
```

However without it my solution is much more chaotic:

```
rotateY = [l for l in zip(*bigList)]
productList = [1]* len(bigList)
count = 0
for l in rotateY:
    for i in l:
        productList[count] *= i
    count += 1
print(productList)

[1, 32, 243, 1024, 3125]
```

Comment: This is a very clear and well worded question. I would point out that with the axis argument the numpy approach can be simplified further to `np.prod(bigList, 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And why not simply:

```
productList = []
for i in range(len(bigList[0]):
    p = 1
    for row in bigList:
        p *= row[i]
    productList.append(p)
```

Alternatively, a small improvement over your solution:

```
productList = [1]* len(bigList[0])
for row in bigList:
    for i, c in enumerate(row):
        productList[i] *= c
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over each row getting each row's *n*-th element, and multiplying each element together:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> 
>>> def mul_lst(lst):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, lst)

>>> 
>>> bigList = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
>>> 
>>> [mul_lst([row[i] for row in bigList]) for i in range(len(bigList))]
[1, 32, 243, 1024, 3125]
```

If you cannot use *any* libraries, including `functools`, you can write the logic for the `mul_lst` function manually:

```
>>> def mul_lst(lst):
    product = lst[0]
    for el in lst[1:]:
        product *= el
    return product

>>> mul_lst([3, 3])
9
>>> mul_lst([2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
32
```

Comment: "**Let's say I'm not allowed to use libraries.**" - I would say it includes `functools`…

Comment: @Błotosmętek I took that as meaning libraries like NumPy or Pandas. But I'll update with a version that doesn't use `functools`.

Comment: @Błotosmętek Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

We can *transpose* the nested list and then use `reduce` (a Python built-in) in Python 2.x on each element (list) for a one-liner -

```
>>> [reduce(lambda a,b: a*b, i) for i in map(list, zip(*bigList))]
[1, 32, 243, 1024, 3125]
```

Comment: _" `reduce` (a Python built-in)"_ - Note that `reduce` was _only_ a builtin in Python 2. [In Python 3, it was removed in favor of `functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick recursive solution

```
def prod(x):
  """ Recursive approach with behavior of np.prod over axis 0 """
  if len(x) is 1:
      return x
  for i, a_ in enumerate(x.pop()):
      x[0][i] *= a_
  return prod(x)
```